# is it possible to combine pixelsearch and pixelgetcolor

Tags: autohotkey

In this MMO game, if my character has low HP it's supposed to teleport back to town and talk to the healer NPC. It's not working and I can't figure out why - I get errors when I try to run my script.

http://i61.tinypic.com/swqltw.jpg

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Relative
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative
Home:: ;press home to start ahk


Loop   

PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00ff00, 0, fast ;<<<--this is the monster color to attack
if(ErrorLevel=0) 
Sleep, 200
Send, {F4}
Sleep, 200
MouseClick, left, 392, 289
Sleep, 8000


else 

   PixelGetColor, healthbar, 51, 82 ;heres my health bar coordinates

  if (healthbar = 0xDEDED6) ;if my hp bar goes low it will go teleport to town and click to healer npc
       Send !3 ;alt 3 to teleport to town
       Sleep 5000 ;lets wait 5seconds for waiting game loading.
       MouseClick, left, 755, 341 ;click the healer npc
       sleep, 1500
       Send {F5} ;some self skill buffs and stuffs
       sleep, 1500
       Send {F5}
       sleep, 1500
       MouseClick, left, 755, 341   ;click to healer npc again to heal mana
       sleep, 500
       MouseClick, left, 713, 281 ;click to teleporter npc to get back to dungeon to kill monsters
       sleep, 500
       Send {Enter}
       sleep, 1500
       Send {Enter}
else 
       Send {F8} ;if no monster present in screen, use random teleport skill to search for monsters


F11::Pause
End::ExitApp ; alt+x to exit ahk
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: heres my errors http://i61.tinypic.com/swqltw.jpg im really confuse alot in if and else sorry im really newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a very essential part of programming in all non-lowlevel-programming languages: **Braces**. (In AutoIt, I think you don't use braces but `if` and `endif` / `wend`s etc. instead which is basically the same

It is important to understand that the compiler in AutoHotkey does not care about the indentations in your script.

Quick example:

```
if(healthbar = 0xDEDED6)
send, !3
sleep, 5000
```

will be the same as

```
if(healthbar = 0xDEDED6)
{
    send !3
}
sleep, 5000
```

. So, `sleep, 5000` will be executed in any way, regardless of the if-statement! If you are not using any braces at all, any `if`-statements, `loop`s, `else` parts etc. will only count for *one line*. So, never omit braces, ONLY if there ist just **one** line to be executed.

If you want to be sure, then use braces wherever you can.

Another thing: If you start any section with a hotkey trigger like `home::`, then be sure to enclose it with `return` in the end.

Here's an example of your source code. I also changed some indentations, but be aware that they are not necessary, only for better readability.

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Relative
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative

Home:: ;press home to start ahk

Loop
{

    PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00ff00, 0, fast ;<<<--this is the monster color to attack
    if(ErrorLevel=0)
    {
        Sleep, 200
        Send, {F4}
        Sleep, 200
        MouseClick, left, 392, 289
        Sleep, 8000
    }
    else
    {
        PixelGetColor, healthbar, 51, 82 ;heres my health bar coordinates
        if (healthbar = 0xDEDED6) ;if my hp bar goes low it will go teleport to town and click to healer npc
        {
           Send !3 ;alt 3 to teleport to town
           Sleep 5000 ;lets wait 5seconds for waiting game loading.
           MouseClick, left, 755, 341 ;click the healer npc
           sleep, 1500
           Send {F5} ;some self skill buffs and stuffs
           sleep, 1500
           Send {F5}
           sleep, 1500
           MouseClick, left, 755, 341   ;click to healer npc again to heal mana
           sleep, 500
           MouseClick, left, 713, 281 ;click to teleporter npc to get back to dungeon to kill monsters
           sleep, 500
           Send {Enter}
           sleep, 1500
           Send {Enter}
        }
        else 
           Send {F8} ;if no monster present in screen, use random teleport skill to search for monsters
    }

}

return  ; ------ end of HOME hotkey


F11::Pause
End::ExitApp ; alt+x to exit ahk
```

However, that's no guarantee your code will work now

Comment: Great :D if you need any further help, call